# Ask for the Node-RED version inside a function node

Tags: javascript, node.js, runtime, version, node-red

My aim is it to have code in a function node, which asks for the Node-RED runtime version number. Some of the following code within this function node should not be executed dependent on the version number.

This is important for me since I am working on two different versioned systems. My development system is version > 1.0.0 and my productive system is version < 1.0.0.

I found the [Node-RED runtime API](https://nodered.org/docs/api/modules/v/1.0/@node-red_runtime.html) but I saw that the API is not available for the Node-RED editor.

How can I ask for the runtime version number inside a function node?

Edit 1:
I found a possiblity to use environment variables. Is the version of Node-RED part of the environmant variables? [Link](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/environment-variables). I am working with Linux Debian and Windows10.

```
let foo = env.get("FOO");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1.0, the `node.done()` api was added to the Function node. You could use a test for its existence as a proxy for knowing if you are running in pre-1.0 or not.

```
if (!!node.done) {
   // pre-1.0
} else {
   // 1.0 or later
}
```